# Table sorter Loading Dynamic Data [Ajax, Json,C#]

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, tablesorter

I was applying table sorter plugin on a ajax table which i update dynamically.

on first page sorting is working ok 
but on 2nd 3rd page sorting is not working if i use `$("#gvMainTemp > tbody > tr").hide();`to hide previous data on 2nd 3rd page...

If i remove `$("#gvMainTemp > tbody > tr").hide();` it will bind 1st page data on 2nd 3rd..... 

and will only sort 1st page data on 2nd and third page also

pluging used :

[TableSorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html) with Fixed Header

[My Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmxsnnw2/)  for reference

Answer (score 0):

When paging data within the table, it would be best to remove any previous rows within the table as you would have to keep track of those rows and maintain a reference. The example code above does not appear to do this, so if the user returns to a previously viewed page, duplicate rows are being added to the table.

Instead of using `.hide()`, use `.remove()`.

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
  $("#gvMainTemp > tbody > tr").remove();
  // ...
}
```

It at all possible, it might be easier to use the included pager widget/addon to provide ajax interaction.